# Can browserify set global modules?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, browserify

I'm putting together a Backbone Marionette application with Browserify. When I want to use Backbone or Marionette related functions, the top of each individual module file looks like this:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var _ = require('underscore');
var Backbone = require('backbone'); Backbone.$ = $;
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');
```

Is there a way do not have to define this at the top of every file? I want my code to be as DRY as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the **DRY** principle is against this, but unfortunately there is nothing within **Browserify** for setting global modules. Because of this, setting global modules would be possible if you would append those modules to `global` or `window` but even with the risk of going a bit off-track with the **DRY** principle, the way you're doing it now is still better than using `global` or `window` which is a bad practice